# multidimensional array filtering javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional array

```
[
  ["apple" , 50],
  ["pie", 45]
  ["steak", 78]
]
```

I have one another array

```
["apple","pie"]
```

How can I filter first array into this result:

```
[
    ["apple" , 50],
    ["pie", 45]
]
```

```js
function sorting(value){ 
  var sorted = new Array(); 
  for(var i =0; i <Object.keys(inputArray); i++)
  { 
    if (inputArray[i].keys === value)
    { 
      sorted.push(inputArray[i]); 
    } 
  } 
  return sorted; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this may be your solutionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206914/how-to-filter-multidimensional-javascript-array

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective is for you to show what you have attemted to solve your issue and people help you with **your code** when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: `function sorting(value){
                   var sorted = new Array();
                   for(var i =0; i <Object.keys(inputArray); i++){
                       if (inputArray[i].keys === value){
                           sorted.push(inputArray[i]);
                       }
                   }
                   return sorted;
                }`

Comment: @Rauf Did you find a different answer?

Comment: @SheshankShankar Thanks for your help. worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var firstArray = [
  ["apple" , 50],
  ["pie", 45],
  ["steak", 78]
];
var secondArray = ["apple","pie"];

var thirdArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
  if (secondArray.includes(firstArray[i][0])) {
    thirdArray.push(firstArray[i]);
  }
}
console.log(thirdArray);
```

This is of course used if you don't want to use the .filter method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const arr1 = [
  ["apple", 50],
  ["pie", 45],
  ["steak", 78]
]

const arr2 = ["apple", "pie"]

const result = arr1.filter(e => arr2.includes(e[0]))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: why you stringify the end result?

Comment: Just for display purposes , not necessary