# Vue accessing an array within in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to access data from a prop that has an array within an array, I have to type tons of `v-for` statements to access the data.

Currently I have to cycle through the `spaces` array (check if their id matches with the one I want) and use an `v-if` statement to output only the one I want, then I repeat that cycle for `rooms` (check ids again).

Is there a way to `filter` through arrays within arrays? Without these for/if statements? I've been reading into filters but haven't been able to figure it out for what I need.

Vue file:

```
               <v-flex hidden-sm-and-down sm4 lg4 class="sidebarSticky">
                    <v-layout v-for="space in spaces"
                              v-if="space.id === selectedSpace"
                              :key="space.id"
                    >
                        <!-- 1 room details -->
                        <v-flex v-for="room in space.rooms"
                                v-if="selectedRoom === room.id"
                                v-if="selectedRoom "
                                :key="room.id">
                            <v-card>
                                <v-card-text>

                                    <!-- room name -->
                                    <h2 class="sidebarRoomName"> {{ room.name }} </h2>
                                    <!-- description -->
                                    <p> {{ room.description }} </p>

                                </v-card-text>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </v-flex>
```

My Data:

```
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
            selectedSpace: 0;
            selectedRoom: 1,
            spaces: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'House in Amsterdam',
                    rooms: [
                        {
                            id: 0,
                            name: 'My epic living room'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'My epic room'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'House in Paris',
                    rooms: [
                        {
                            id: 0,
                            name: 'My epic bathroom'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
    })
```

The code above might seem very simple, but I'm working with a lot more data and it can be super difficult to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter multidimensional javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206914/how-to-filter-multidimensional-javascript-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yep, don't do that with `v-for`. Create yourself some computed properties and use `Array.filter()`, then in your template, point the computed property.

```
computed: {
    selectedSpaceObj() {
        return this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id === this.selectedSpace)
    },
    selectedRoomObj() {
        return this.selectedSpaceObj.rooms
            .filter(aRoom => aRoom.id === this.selectedRoom)                
    }
}
```

Do it all in javascript. It will lead to much more readable code, and you will likely reuse the computed property all over the place. For `selectedRoomObj`, for example, we can just reuse the computed `selectedSpaceObj`.

Next, for code readability, and to avoid long accessors, create yourself space and room components. Nested v-for loops is a sure sign that you need them.

The problems you encounter might lead you to rethink the structure of your data. Perhaps you want to store selected as a property directly on the room and space objects? Perhaps it makes more sense to have 1 root level rooms array, with a "foreign key" into spaces?

Comment: I edited out the `me` variable as it's not necessary when using arrow functions.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks for the extra help man! I'm having an issue with the `selectedRoomObj()`, it is receiving an error of: `vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`. Eventhough it has a value. This is how I'm using it: `<v-card v-for="room in selectedRoomObj" :key="room.id">
                {{ room.id }}
            </v-card>` This works for the `selectedSpaceObj` but not for the room!

Comment: Ok you'll need to modify your computed `selectedRoomObj` so that it never returns `undefined`. If filter finds nothing, `return {};` To be safe, you should do the same thing for selectedSpace :-)

Comment: @EmileBergeron `selectedRoomObj() {
                if (this.selectedSpaceObj == null) {
                    return {};
                } else {
                    this.selectedSpaceObj.rooms.filter(aRoom => aRoom.id === this.selectedRoom)
                }
            }` Is this correct? I'm still getting the same error:/ It still says it `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`

Comment: Change your test. Try... `if (!this.selectedSpaceObj || !this.selectedSpaceObj.rooms || this.selectedSpaces.rooms.length === 0) { return {}; }` That will deal with `undefined` as well.

Comment: @bbsimonbb It should be be working but for some reason when the page loads, it runs `selectedRoomObj` twice, eventhough I'm only using it once on my page. Then I figured out that in my `mounted()` I set my default value for the `this.selectedRoom` and `this.selectedSpace`. Could this be affecting my outcome? If I change `mounted()` to `created()` it works.

Comment: You shouldn't care about how many times these things run, or when. They run whenever they need to. I can't see why mounted or created should make any difference, but I can't see your code.